# SCCM Management Point in DNS

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, sccm

I wonder how can one find information about existing SCCM management points in domain. I know that it's possible to implement nslookup -type=any _mssms_mp_*Site_code*._tcp.*Domain*. But what if I don't know the site code? Is it possible to find management point without this knowledge?

Comment: I would say this question is better suited on [superuser](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: I'd say better suited for [sf] as SCCM is certainly "professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration"

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how complex your setup is and to some point also on the configuration of your whole site but if you only use one site and have the site publish data to your ad it can be done. MPs are then stored in "CN=System Management,CN=System,[your domain]", Named SMS-MP-[Sitecode]-[FQDN]" and they should have a property called MSSMSDefaultMP which tells you the default one if there are more than one.
You could search for them with powershell like this:

```
$ADSysMgmtContainer = [ADSI]("LDAP://CN=System Management,CN=System,[your domain]")
$AdSearcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(Name=SMS-MP-*)(objectClass=mSSMSManagementPoint))"
$AdSearcher.SearchRoot = $ADSysMgmtContainer
$ADManagementPoint = $AdSearcher.FindAll() | where {$_.Properties.mssmsdefaultmp -eq $true}
$ADManagementPoint.Properties.dnshostname
```

Of course this all assumes you do this from a server that is not part of the site because if you have the sccm client installed on the machine you do the query from you can just look the site up. You can read more on the prerequisites and how MP discovery is generally done [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/plan-design/hierarchy/understand-how-clients-find-site-resources-and-services).

Comment: Yes, but it's possible if SCCM publishes information to the AD. But if AD scheme wans't extended or SCCM doesn't publish there information about it's sites? That't why I'd like to find MPs in DNS or WINS

Comment: This is why I said it depends. Extending the AD and publishing there is the default afaik but not necessary. But any site admin should be in a position to know how his site is configured. The problem with answering this for all possible configurations is that there is really a lot of complicated stuff that you could possibly have, multiple domains maybe also multiple sites. In this case you could never find the MP without knowing the site because more than one would be published. So I cannot give you an answer for all cases only for specific ones, sorry.